# scope.$watch is not working while changing in controller angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, angularjs-scope

I have created a common directive for datepicker control. Here i am using JQuery UI Datepicker. In my directive while retrieving data from database, scope.$watch is working fine but when i am changing in the controller it is not detected in scope.$wwatch

My directive

```
common.directive("datepickerDate", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {    
            var updateModel = function (dateText) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                });
            };
            var options = {
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    var dateParts = dateText.split('/');
                    updateModel(dateParts[2] + "/" + (dateParts[1] - 1) + "/" + dateParts[0]);
                },                
            };          
            elem.datepicker(options);
            scope.$watchCollection(ngModelCtrl, function () {
                if (ngModelCtrl.$modelValue) {
                    elem.datepicker("setDate", new Date(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue));
                }
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML Code

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in dateList">
       <input type="text" ng-model="row.fromdate" datepicker-date />
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

My Controller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.dateList, function(data){
    data.fromdate = "14/05/2016";
});
```

while retrieving from the database $watch is working but while i am using in angular.forEach and change the scope value is not working.

Comment: Please check the scope of variables related to directive and controller.. whether its in $scope/ or $scope.$parent. then do required changes.

Comment: No its only $scope. and while retrieving from the database using services its working but after changing inside the function its not working